# Replace SSL cert on a CloudFront Distribution without downtime

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront, aws-certificate-manager

I have an existing CloudFront Distribution, we validated with email before the DNS validation, we would like to switch to DNS validation from Email, not finding a easy way to switchover without downtime.

Is there a way to switch SSL validation with AWS CloudFront without changing the cert?

or If I create a new a cert, is it possible to replace without downtime?

Comment: Are you using ACM?

Comment: Yes. I'm using ACM along with CloudFront.

Comment: Yes. You can create multiple certs for the same domain, not sure if I replace I will have a downtime. Even few minutes will cost us a lot.

Comment: Best place to get this clarified will be AWS support. :) You can move forward with confidence then.

Comment: There will be a downtime for this if you replace. No downtime if you keep your old certificate. [Refer here](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=908135)

Comment: Thanks for the link. Can you please add that as an answer. That solves the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the response for [this thread in AWS forums](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=908135), there might be some downtime if you're going to replace the certificate. But as long as you keep the old one there might not be any problem.

> As long as your old certificate is still valid then there won't be any downtime in any of the cases.

Comment: Good find, though I'm not sure where you are seeing that "there might be some downtime."  If you create a new certificate and switch the CloudFront configs to use it, then there's no reason for any downtime.  Also, ACM refuses to allow you to delete the old cert until no resources are still using it -- ["You cannot delete an ACM Certificate that is being used by another AWS service."](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/acm/latest/userguide/gs-acm-delete.html) -- so you can't accidentally/unknowingly delete the old cert until it is safe to do do.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot I guess AWS representative also missed this ;)